# Image clicking with python pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I tried to find it but this is wrong I don't understand what `event.pos` means from the place I found this code. When I click on the image it doesn't print "clicked" and this is because it thinks that the image starts at x and y 0...

I never used *Stack Overflow* so hope I get an answer.

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    x,y=event.pos
    if playbutton.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
        print("clicked")
```

why was this reopened after two whole years lol

Comment: *"I found this code. [...]"* - Where did you find this code? It is wrong.

Comment: https://blog.penjee.com/mouse-clicked-on-image-in-pygame/

Comment: I see. What a pity. This code is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top leftof the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

    x, y = event.pos
    button_rect = playbutton.get_rect(topleft = (button_x, button_y))

    if button_rect .collidepoint(x, y):
        print("clicked")
```

Comment: Do I place the button's x and y on the button_x and button_y place?
Also what topleft mean there...Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: @Mr.Raptor (`button_x`, `button_y`) is the top left corner of the button. It is the location where you `blit` the button.